# JSF 2.0 Temlating and injection of MB || CDI bean

Tags: java, templates, jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-6

Problem: managed bean not injecting by template.

Goal: I wan to decelerate logout button in template.

Scenario: I am building j2ee 6 application with jsf 2.0 for web part.

template file layout/template.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >
<h:head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="/resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/resources/css/cssLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Facelets Template</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="baner" class="baner" >
        <ui:insert name="baner" >
            <h:panelGrid style="color:blue; width:100%; height:100px;" border="5">
                Baner Name go here
            </h:panelGrid>
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ui:insert name="menu">
            some...
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="top" class="top">
        <ui:insert name="top">Top Section</ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="left">
            <ui:insert name="left">                
                <h:commandButton value="Do log out" action="#{securityBacking.invalidate}" />
                <h:commandButton value="log out" action="#{securityBacking.logout}" />
            </ui:insert>
            <!--log out-->
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="left_content">
            <ui:insert name="content">Main Content</ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

tempalte client index.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:vt="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/security">
<body>

<ui:composition template="layout/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="top">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid border="4">
                <!--TODO add i18n-->
                <p style="color:red;">Partner`s login.</p>
                <vt:loginPanel/>               

                <f:view>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{rulesBean.userPrincipalName}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{rulesBean.user}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{rulesBean.manager}"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Do log out" action="#{securityBacking.invalidate}" />
                    <h:commandButton value="log out" action="#{securityBacking.logout}" />
                </f:view>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</body>
</html>
```

faces declaration in web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

SecurityBacking.java :

```
@Named("securityBacking")
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityBacking {


    public String logout() {
        String result = "/login?faces-redirect=true";
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.
                getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try {
            System.out.println("calling logout");
            request.logout();
            System.out.println("called logout");
        } catch (ServletException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SecurityBacking.class.getName()).
                    log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            result = "/loginError?faces-redirect=true";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isInRole(String role) {
        ExternalContext external = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) external.getRequest();
        String user = request.getRemoteUser();

        return request.isUserInRole("partner");
    }

    public void invalidate() {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
            request.getSession(false).invalidate();
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

---

As you see :

```
<h:commandButton value="log out" action="#{securityBacking.logout}" />
```

and

```
<h:commandButton value="Do log out" action="#{securityBacking.invalidate}" />
```

are decelerated in layout/template.xhtml & index.xhtml, but buttons decelerated in layout/template.xhtml not working in the sam time, they working in index.xhtml.

When i looking to Safari web inspector i see :

for decelerated in index.xhtml

```
<input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="submit" name="j_idt12:j_idt29" value="log out" />
```

and for layout/template.xhtml

```
<input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="submit" name="j_idt32" value="log out" />
```

As I understand bean not injecting daclets template inside  tag, but I haven`t find anything about this in j2ee 6 tutorials & spec, or maybe рфмут'е notice such information.

Q1: Am I right about injection?

Q2: Why It is not injecting through templating ?

Q3: What is the different way to templating in this case?

Q4: What is the best practice for this case?

(I am using glassfish v3 web server)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons in your template are not nested in an `<h:form>`.  Move the `<h:form>` elements out of your index.xhtml, and into your template, or wrap the template buttons in a secondary form.

Comment: Thank you!
I lose it some where )